# Kotlin MVVM Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, mvvm

How i can remove this carsListener?
Otherwise I get an infinite download

```
 override fun getUserData(userId: String): Flow<Response<User>> = callbackFlow {
        Response.Loading
        val userClients = arrayListOf<Client>()
        val clientsListener = firestore
            .collection("users").document(userId).collection("clients")
            .addSnapshotListener { clients, e ->
                if (clients != null) {
                    for (client in clients) {
                        val carsList = arrayListOf<Car>()
                        val carsListener = firestore
                            .collection("users").document(userId)
                            .collection("clients").document(client.id)
                            .collection("cars")
                            .addSnapshotListener { cars, error ->
                                if (cars != null) {
                                    for (car in cars) {
                                        val carsData = car.toObject(Car::class.java)
                                        carsList.add(carsData)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        val data = client.toObject(Client::class.java)
                        userClients.add(data.copy(cars = carsList))
                    }
                } else
                    Response.Error(e?.message ?: e.toString())
            }
        val snapShotListener = firestore.collection("users").document(userId)
            .addSnapshotListener { user, error ->
                val response = if (user != null) {
                    val userData = user.toObject(User::class.java)
                    Response.Success<User>(userData?.copy(clients = userClients)!!)
                } else
                    Response.Error(error?.message ?: error.toString())
                trySend(response).isSuccess
            }
        awaitClose {
            clientsListener.remove()
            snapShotListener.remove()
        }
    }
```

I tried everything, but it didn't give any result
if you know how to do it differently, please tell me

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you have nested collections: `Users` > `Clients` > `Cars`. In this case, you don't need to add Snapshot Listeners to all those collections. You can simply attach a listener to `Users` and then call `get()` to get the data from its subcollections.

Also, starting in [version 24.4.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#firestore-ktx_v24-4-0) of the Cloud Firestore Android SDK ([BoM 31.0.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#bom_v31-0-0)) you can take advantage of:

- the [snapshots()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/ktx/package-summary#(com.google.firebase.firestore.Query).snapshots(com.google.firebase.firestore.MetadataChanges)) function which returns a `Flow<QuerySnapshot>` so that you don't have to write your own implementation of `CallbackFlow`.
- the [await()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/await.html) function which allows you to await for the result of a `CollectionReference.get()`.

Be sure to update to the latest Firebase version on your `app/build.gradle` file to be able to use these functions.
And putting it all together should result in a code that looks like this:

```kotlin
    override fun getUserData(userId: String): Flow<Response<User>> {
        val userRef = firestore.collection("users").document(userId)
        val clientsRef = userRef.collection("clients")
        return userRef.snapshots().map { documentSnapshot ->
            // Convert the DocumentSnapshot to User class
            val fetchedUser = documentSnapshot.toObject<User>()!!

            // Fetch the clients for that User
            val clientsSnapshot = clientsRef.get().await()
            // iterate through each client to fetch their cars
            val clients = clientsSnapshot.documents.map { clientDoc ->
                // Convert the fetched client
                val client = clientDoc.toObject<Client>()!!

                // Fetch the cars for that client
                val carsSnapshot = clientsRef.document(clientDoc.id)
                    .collection("cars").get().await()
                // Convert the fetched cars
                val cars = carsSnapshot.toObjects<Car>()
                client.copy(cars = cars)
            }

            Response.Success(fetchedUser.copy(clients = clients))
        }.catch { error ->
            Response.Error<User>(error.message ?: error.toString())
        }
    }
```

---

As a side note: Reading from all these 3 collections at once can become expensive, depending on the number of Documents that each collection contains. That's due to [how Firestore pricing works](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) - you get charged for each document read.

Consider adjusting your database structure to help save costs. Here are some resources that could be helpful:

- [Cloud Firestore Data Model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model)
- [Structure Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data)
- [Understand Cloud Firestore Billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing)
- [Cloud Firestore Pricing | Get to know Cloud Firestore #3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NegFl9p_sE)
- [Example Cloud Firestore costs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example)